# $f \mapsto \int f^2$ is $L^1$-weakly lower semicontinuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

If $f \in C(\mathbb [0,1], \mathbb R)$ is $$ f \mapsto \int_0^1 f(t)^2\  dt$$
$L^1$-weakly lower semicontinuous? I.e. if $$\int_0^1 f_n g \rightarrow \int_0^1 f g$$ for every $g \in L^{\infty}$, then $$ \int_0^1 f^2 \leq \liminf_n \int_0^1 f_n^2 \qquad ? $$

Comment: Choose $g = f$ and use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: @DanielFischer Of course, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A continuous function on $[0,1]$ is bounded, hence the choice $g:=f$ is allowed. This gives 
$$\int f^2dx=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\int f_nfdx.$$
By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, 
$$\int f_nfdx\leqslant \sqrt{\int f_n^2 dx}\cdot \sqrt{\int f^2 dx},$$
hence
$$\int f^2dx\leqslant \liminf_{n\to+\infty}\sqrt{\int f_n^2 dx}\cdot \sqrt{\int f^2 dx}.$$
The result follows considering the cases $f\equiv 0$ and $f\neq 0$.